# Install SSH-Server on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-10.04, openssh

I need to use an old Ubuntu distribution (10.04) 32bit for compatibility reasons.
I have to run it in hyper v, thus i need to get a SSH connection to the system up and running.

I adjusted the **/etc/apt/sources.list** to include **old-releases.ubuntu.com** so that i can update and upgrade.

When Trying to install ssh-server / openssh-server using

```
sudo apt-get install ssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

the following message is shown:

> packet ssh-server has no installation candidate

Any suggestions on how to install either ssh-server or openssh-server on this machine?

Any help or workarounds are appreciated!

Comment: May be it is easier to just download an stand-alone ssh server like Dropbear and install it manually?

Comment: Can you find the package in `apt-cache search ssh`?

Comment: [ubuntu.se] might be a better place to ask.

Comment: Up through v. 16.04 LTS, there were 32-bit versions (and upgrade from 16.04 32-bit to 18.04 32-bit is possible). You might try a live USB with a later version of Ubuntu to see if it's compatible with your SSH needs.

Comment: @Kenster [it wasn't, though](https://askubuntu.com/q/1236269/11316). Actually AskUbuntu is rather strict about what's on-topic. Heck questions about upcoming releases can be off-topic one hour and on-topic the next. Also they don't care about Ubuntu derivatives, which is ironic, looking at Ubuntu as Debian-derivative. And for Mint so many things apply to Ubuntu out of the box. Oh and last but not least I find AskUbuntu more rude and less appreciative of _questions and answers_ alike than other SE sites I frequent (less upvotes, even less on questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, back that VM up.

Please, follow these steps bellow:

1. try to run **sudo apt-get update** (To update your package repository).
2. Then, try to run **sudo apt-get install openssh-server** (To install the ssh server).

***Important Note***: Don't need run **sudo apt-get install ssh-server** because just **sudo apt-get install openssh-server** enough to install the full ssh server.

Follow a copy of **/etc/apt/sources.list** file content bellow:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse
# deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb http://old-releases.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
# deb-src http://old-releases.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
```

Here in my VM these steps worked very well.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me.
It seems like i did not fully fix the /etc/apt/sources.list.

Comment: @Bassrelic you should upvote in addition to accepting, if this really helped you.

Comment: @ 0xC0000022L i did but i had not the previleges for it to be shown (possible that i removed the vote by klicking twice though)
Sorry for that!

Comment: @jluizsouzadev just one remark, applying `sed` to do the replacement would have been more sensible, simply because you don't know which lines were originally enabled or not for the OP. Basically something along the lines of `sed -i.bak -E 's|://[a-z0-9\.]+/ubuntu|://old-releases/ubuntu|g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @Bassrelic yep, clicking again removes the vote unless it has been locked (which happens after 5 minutes or so ... and can be undone if the post - question _or_ answer - gets edited again).

Comment: @0xC0000022L Thanks. Instead I just used **vim** editor with the command **"%s/string1/string2/g"** to replace those strings.